# Sencha app not displaying anything in tomcat server?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have developed application using sencha architect and just start tomcat server and try to deploy it but its not showing anything(Blank page).

Please suggest some useful example or tutorials..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/index.html. Also you can download the examples along with Sencha Touch SDK.